# Call webservice through javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-services

I have an web service running on `http://remoteip:8080/TestService` I want to call it through java script this service takes parameters in JSON format
`{"status":"F","subscriber":[{"PhoneNumber": 1234567890}, {"PhoneNumber":0123456789}]}` like this how can I implement this in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function callWebService() {

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'http://remoteip:8080/TestService',
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "status": "F",
                    "PhoneNumber":"0123456789",
                    .....
                    .....
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.dir(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, err) {
                    alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
                    alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
                },
                complete: function () {
                }
            });      
    }

</script>
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Second parameter expects array of phone numbers can you help me with this?

Comment: Create array of phone numbers and pass array object to "PhoneNumber": phoneNumberArray

Comment: can you help me with syntax

Comment: var phoneNumbers = [1234567890, 0123456789];
var phoneNumbersJson = JSON.stringify(phoneNumbers); 
    data:{
        PhoneNumber: phoneNumbersJson
    }

Comment: `var phoneNumbers = [1234567890, 0123456789]; 
    var phoneNumbersJson = JSON.stringify(phoneNumbers); 
                url: 'http://104.155.141.228:8080/updatesubscriber_status',
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "status": "F",
                    "PhoneNumber":"phoneNumbersJson"
                },`  Is this correct

Comment: "PhoneNumber": phoneNumbersJson


phoneNumbersJson is an object so don't put it in ""